# SelectPDF for .Net :DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified module could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to generate pdf from html. I am using [SelectPdf for .Net](https://selectpdf.com/demo-mvc/ConvertHtmlCodeToPdf).
When I try to generate pdf, I get this error:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified
>   module could not be found.

My primary Guide is [This Documentation on their official website](https://selectpdf.com/demo-mvc/ConvertHtmlCodeToPdf)

[image]
[image]
SettingsController.cs

```
[Route ("settings/aaa")]
    public IActionResult GeneratePdf () {

        return View ();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route ("settings/aaa")]
    public IActionResult GeneratePdf (IFormCollection collection) {
        // read parameters from the webpage
        string htmlString = collection["TxtHtmlCode"];
        string baseUrl = collection["TxtBaseUrl"];

        int webPageWidth = 1024;


        int webPageHeight = 1280;

        // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
        HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf ();

        converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;;
        converter.Options.WebPageWidth = webPageWidth;
        converter.Options.WebPageHeight = webPageHeight;

        // create a new pdf document converting an url
        PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString (htmlString, baseUrl);

        // save pdf document
        byte[] pdf = doc.Save ();

        // close pdf document
        doc.Close ();
        // return resulted pdf document
        FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult (pdf, "application/pdf");
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Document.pdf";
        return fileResult;

    }
```

GeneratePdf.cshtml

```
<div>
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="GeneratePdf">
        <input value="stuff" name="TxtHtmlCode"/>
        <input value="" name="TxtBaseUrl"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

My goal is to make SelectPdf generate pdf from "TxtHtmlCode" input.

Comment: According to [SelectPdf.com](https://selectpdf.com/docs/Installation.htm): Note 2: The .NET Core version is for .NET Core 2.0 or above through .NET Standard 2.0. Currently it **requires a Windows system** to run. It does **not** work on **Linux or Mac or Xamarin**.

Comment: Right. Figured it out recently and installed this dll through homebrew. I have another dll missing now. It's Mac's fault too. Thanks